# Kafka - consuming messages based on timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm kind of new to Kafka but need to implement the logic for the consumer to consume from a particular topic based on timestamp. Another use case is also for me to be able to consume for a particular time range (for example from 10:00 to 10:20). The range will always be dividable by 5 minutes - meaning I won't need to consume from for example 10:00 to 10:04). The logic I was thinking would be as follows:

1. create a table where I store timestamp and Kafka messageId (timestamp | id)
2. create a console\service which does the following every 5 minutes:
3. Get all partitions for a topic
4. Query all partitions for min offset value (a starting point)
5. Store the offset and timestamp in the table

Get all partitions for a topic

Now if everything is alright I should have something like this in the table:

```
10:00     | 0
10:05     | 100
10:10     | 200
HH: mm     | (some number)
```

Now having this I could start the consumer at any time and knowing the offsets I should be able to consume just what I need.
Does it look right or have I made a flaw somewhere? Or maybe there is a better way of achieving the required result? Any thoughts or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

P.S.: one of my colleagues suggested to use partition and work out with each partition separately... Meaning if I got a topic and replica count is for example 5 - then I'd need to save offsets 5 times for my topic for every interval (once per partition). And then the consumer would also need to account for the partitions and consume based on what offsets I got for each partition. But this would kind of incorporate additional complexity which I am trying to avoid...

Thanks in advance!

BR,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

No need for tables.

You can use the seek method of a Consumer instance to move all partitions to an offset defined by that partition.

Partitioning might work... 12 partitions of 5 minute message intervals

I don't think replication addresses your problem.